# Can we make visualforce page as Home page in salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

i want to make my visualforce page as home page in my sandbox.
 So is it possible to make visualforce page as home page in salesforce.

Answer (score 6):

I can think of two things that might work for you.

You can [embed a Visualforce Page in your home page layout](http://www.forcetree.com/2009/12/adding-visualforce-page-to-home-page.html)

Similarly, you could create an HTML area home page component with a little javascript that redirects from the home page to the visualforce page:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.location.replace("/apex/YourVfPage");
<script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.
What you can do is, build a visualforce page, create a tab for that, add that tab to your application and make that as the default tab.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned above - one thing you can try is the following:

1. Create the visualforce page
2. Create a custom tab for that visualforce page called "Home" (or whatever you want to call it)
3. Remove the default "Home" tab from the list of tabs a user sees (can be done via customizing the tabs & profile editing)
4. Add your new Home tab to the user and make it their default tab

I believe that should accomplish what you're wanting to do.

Comment: It's not possible to remove the home tab in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

No We can't make visualforce page as home page in classic in  Lightning it is possible to make it as a home page.

or

you want to by click on the tab to display the visualforce page is possible using visalforce tab.